# What happened about inet_ntoa?

Tags: c, sockets

Let me be puzzled,the example with A different result.Is it somewhere wrong with me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in src;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;

    memset(&src, 0, sizeof(src));
    src.sin_addr.s_addr = 0xEBAE277D;

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = 0x6700A8C0;

    printf("saddr:%s\n", inet_ntoa(src.sin_addr));
    printf("daddr:%s\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
    printf("src:%15s------->dest:%15s\n", inet_ntoa(src.sin_addr), inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
}
```

the result:

```
saddr:125.39.174.235
daddr:192.168.0.103
src: 125.39.174.235------->dest: 125.39.174.235
```

Comment: What's wrong here?

Comment: the result of  "src: 125.39.174.235------->dest: 125.39.174.235"  is  right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `inet_ntoa` says:

> The inet_ntoa() function converts the Internet host address in, given in network byte order, to a string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation. The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite.

(That's from the Linux man page; others have different wording but the warning about the static buffer should be in there somewhere)

So you called `inet_ntoa` once, the buffer was filled, and a pointer to it was returned. You called it again, the buffer was overwritten, and a pointer to it was returned again. You passed both of those pointers to `printf`, and it printed the buffer contents twice.

To do this properly, you need to copy the first `inet_ntoa` result into your own local buffer before calling it again, or just use 2 `printf`s.

Or you can use `inet_ntop` instead, which requires you to provide the output buffer yourself. (Caller-provided output buffers are more common in newer interfaces; static output buffers seem easy at first but in the long run cause accidents like the one in your code.)

Comment: Nices, Thank you very much.